# Combinatorial proof of identity $\sum_{k=0}^{\min(a,b)}\binom{x+y+k}{k}\binom{x}{b-k}\binom{y}{a-k} = \binom{x+a}{b}\binom{y+b}{a}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I try to make a *combinatorial* proof of the identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\min(a,b)}\binom{x+y+k}{k}\binom{x}{b-k}\binom{y}{a-k} = \binom{x+a}{b}\binom{y+b}{a}.$$

It is an exercise problem in Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics (exercise 1.3 (d)). The answer in the book refers to the article

> G. E. Andrews, *Identities in combinatorics I: on sorting two ordered sets*, Discrete Math. **11** (1975), 97–106.

The article deals with similar, but not the same identity. From the proofs in the article, I try to find the meaning of each term of LHS and RHS.

I guess the RHS of the identity counts the number of pair $(A,B)$ of subsets of $S = \{\alpha_x , \cdots, \alpha_1, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_y\}$ (under ascending order) with
$$A \subseteq \{\alpha_a , \cdots, \alpha_1, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_y\},\, |A| = b,$$
$$B \subseteq \{\alpha_x , \cdots, \alpha_1, \beta_1, \cdots, \beta_b\},\, |B| = a.$$

However I can not get the meaning of each term of LHS (i.e. $\binom{x+y+k}{k}\binom{x}{b-k}\binom{y}{a-k}$) What is the meaning of it?

Am I going correct? If it does, how to proceed with the proof? There is another good proof of it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: See also https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h80577p461358 and [Dominique Foata, *Une démonstration combinatoire de l'identité de Pfaff-Saalschütz*, C. R. Acad. Sci., Paris, Sér. I 297, 221-224 (1983)](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6248449w/f5.image.r=Une%20d%C3%A9monstration%20combinatoire%20de%20l'identit%C3%A9%20de%20Pfaff-Saalsch%C3%BCtz?rk=21459;2).