# Combinatorial proof of $\sum_{i=0}^m{\binom{x+y+i}{i} \binom{y}{a-i} \binom{x}{b-i} }=\binom{x+a}{b} \binom{y+b}{a}$

Tags: combinatorics, analysis, generating-functions, combinatorial-proofs

This is *Problem 14* from [here](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Erstan/bij.pdf).

Here's the meaning of *combinatorial proof*:

> The statements in each problem are to be proved combinatorially, in most cases by exhibiting an explicit bijection between two sets. Try to give the most elegant proof possible. Avoid induction, recurrences, generating functions, etc., if at all possible.

And the problem is as follows:

> Find a *combinatorial proof* of:
> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^m{\binom{x+y+i}{i} \binom{y}{a-i} \binom{x}{b-i} }=\binom{x+a}{b} \binom{y+b}{a}
> $$
> where $m=\min(a,b)$.

I have thought the problem for a long time but I failed to find the correct combinatorial construction. Can anyone help?

P.S.: Algebraic proof is also welcomed, since that I don't know how to prove it algebraically either. But it won't be accepted as a final answer to this problem.

**EDIT:** Algebraic proofs have been found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426447/combinatorial-proof-of-identity-sum-k-0-mina-b-binomxykk-binomx), and now only the combinatorial proof is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combinatorial proof of identity $\sum_{k=0}^{\min(a,b)}\binom{x+y+k}{k}\binom{x}{b-k}\binom{y}{a-k} = \binom{x+a}{b}\binom{y+b}{a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426447/combinatorial-proof-of-identity-sum-k-0-mina-b-binomxykk-binomx)

Comment: @darij grinberg No, I am asking for a combinatorial proof. However in that question it is still not given.